# How can I pass TcxLookupDBGridColumns[1] caption to dxstatusbar?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

My cxLookupComboBox1 has listed only two columns received from database table (company_id,company). KeyFieldnames is 'company_id'.

So I am trying to show the company name also but in the status bar like :

```
dxStatusBar1.SimplePanelStyle.Text:=TcxLookupDBGridColumns[1].Caption;
```

Unfortunately this does not work.
What am I missing ? How can I do this ?

Comment: You don't read from the grid. You read from the database it's connected to; the current record in the DB is the one that is selected in the grid.

Comment: I can not do that because the table is opened somewhere else. I am just borrowing the values for a look up.

Comment: If the grid is connected to the table, you can access it. Does it have a DataSet property?

Comment: The dataset property will allow you to get values for each field for the selected record "fieldbyname" etc.

Comment: You can find the solution [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A506)

Comment: @BrakNicku - Thank you... It's working. You can post the answer. I have added it by editing the question.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. If you want to post an answer, do so in the space provided below, just like anyone else would; it's entirely acceptable to [answer your own question here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It's inappropriate to edit your question to add the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution :

```
procedure TForm3.cxLookupComboBox2PropertiesChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
with cxLookupComboBox2.Properties.Grid.DataController do
dxStatusBar1.SimplePanelStyle.Text:= Values[FocusedRecordIndex, 1];
end;
```